# Pushing to git from new folder without git

Tags: git, cloud, bitbucket

I have a `bitbucket` repo inside a MEGA cloud folder.

I have a new notebook where I Downloaded this MEGA cloud project, made some changes and now a I want to push it to bitbucket.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `git pull` from bitbucket, merge and then `git push` to bitbucket again. That should work.

Comment: Can't edit anymore. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10548919/7414040) is a good explanation  of what you basically want to do.